# Redirect 301 in htaccess changes the url encoding

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, encoding

here is my .htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co\.il$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.il/$1 [L,R=301]
```

When i try to enter a url with hebrew in the query string the encoding changes .

For e.g, entering this url :

domain.co.il/subfolder/index.php?title=אלגברה

will result in :

http://www.domain.co.il/subfolder/index.php?title=%25D7%2590%25D7%259C%25D7%2592%25D7%2591%25D7%25A8%25D7%2594

which doesn't exist .

(btw, www.domain.co.il/subfolder/index.php?title=אלגברה works just fine..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co\.il$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

`NE` flag will ensure no encoding while redirecting.